# Показать программно клавиатуру

Tags: android, клавиатура

Добрый день.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как отобразить клавиатуру сразу после отображения фрагмента.
По вопросу нашел несколько путей, но ни один не помог.

```
1) `<EditText ...><requestFocus /></EditText>`

2) InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(myEditText, 0);

3) editText.requestFocus();
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня работает:

```
    getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Может дело в `ALWAYS`

Comment: Не работает. Может, в телефоне так настроено - никогда не показывать сразу клавиатуру? Я только на одном аппарате проверял.

Answer (score 3):

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
        ctx.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```